# Internal Harddrive 2TB 10000RPM

Tags: hard-drive

I have been searching for internal 2TB or 1TB 10000 RPM but couldn't find any on retailer sites. Currently I am using WD 1TB Cavier Black 7200 RPM. This drive makes so much noise and I can't sleep well at night :(

Comment: You do realize that 10k drives tend to be louder than 7.2k drives, right?

Comment: Is it really your drive that is loud?  That may be a sign of a failing drive.  It is difficult to believe that a drive in good condition is noticeably louder then your fans...

Comment: If you want a quieter drive, you need a *slower* drive and better mounting. But see [Noise level of 10'000 rpm harddisks](http://superuser.com/questions/34884/noise-level-of-10000-rpm-harddisks), and especially browse [Silent PC Review](http://www.silentpcreview.com/).

Answer (score 4):

10K RPM drives aren't yet up to the 1TB capacity mark, 600GB is the highest I saw, so these drives don't exist.

Comment: What about SAS drives? If I do not consider price is there any hard drive which provides speed + large size + no noise?

Comment: The largest 10K drives in existence right now are 600GB. Nearly all 7.2K RPM drives are SATA and come in large flavors. If you want capacity, you'll want 7.2K SATA. If you want speed, you'll want 10K (or 15K) SAS.

Comment: If price really is no object in your quest for fast and big, this one (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227517) will be fast and quiet. But cost more than your PC.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll find right now is the [600GB WD Velociraptor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136555), and it costs almost $300.

Next in line is the [Maxtor Momentus SSD Hybrid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003NSBF32).  This is only 500GB and only 7200 RPM, but's is priced a lot better (around $120) and the 4GB SSD cache helps it approach 10000RPM performance or even exceed it in some measures.  This or something like it will likely be my next hard drive purchase.

It sounds like your real problem, though, is two-fold:

1. Mounting.  You can greatly improve noise-level with some inexpensive rubber washers that sit around the screws between the hard drive and mounting carriage.
2. Power management.  Why let the drives run all night? Or the whole computer for that matter?  Let it go to sleep when you do.

Comment: The 600Gb Velociraptor is much cheaper when you're not looking at the price for a "20 pack". ;)  Newegg.ca sells it for C$289.99.